# How to understand if a zip file is corrupt or still being transfered

Tags: c#, zip

i'm trying to write a c# program that checks a ftp folder for files zip.
i wanted to know if there is a way in c# to know if a zip file is broken or simply is still being transfered to my folder.

Thanks

Comment: So the file is being uploaded to the remote site, but you want to know (remotely) if it's done yet?  It's not clear to/from where the files are going.

Comment: If you have no control over the communication channel, you can't reliably detect the difference between a broken file or a file that is still being transferred. You can only try to deduce the difference by watching the file size over a specific period of time and assume that the upload has finished if it didn't change. Even if a ZIP file would contain a header that contains the expected file size - and it might very well, I don't know - you still can't use this information to deduce that the transfer is still in progress. The transfer could have been cancelled or interrupted.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes, i want to know if its done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Open the file you'll get `IOException` which means file in use, else assume it is corrupted

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Depending on the software that performs the upload it might very well allow read access.

Comment: if that is your code doing that you can make sure you dont give access to others, or else you can try to open a file with `ReadWrite` access

Comment: And you can check for Exception message something like `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` to make sure you're doing right